# Appending data to XML file

Tags: php, xml

Im using CubeGallery3D, that stores with XML files.

The XML structure looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/peMxcmYb

I would like to append:

```
    <thumbnail preview="This is Preview" previewURL="This is URL" thumb="This is Thumb">
        <title><![CDATA[This is Title]]></title>
        <discription><![CDATA[This is Description]]></discription>
    </thumbnail>
```

To the XML file, with PHP.

I have started out with this:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('/theme1157/sample.xml');
```

to load the sample.xml.

Can someone show me how I can create a `<thumbnail>` element in the file and add parameter + values to it like the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('sample.xml');



$thumbnail = $xmldoc->createElement('thumbnail');
$thumbnail->setAttribute('preview', 'This is a preview');
$thumbnail->setAttribute('previewURL', 'This is a URL');
$thumbnail->setAttribute('thumb', 'This is a Thumb');

$title = $xmldoc->createElement('title');
$title->appendChild($xmldoc->createCDATASection('This is Title'));
$thumbnail->appendChild($title);


$description = $xmldoc->createElement('description');
$description->appendChild($xmldoc->createCDATASection('This is Description'));
$thumbnail->appendChild($description);


$xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('thumbnails')->item(0)->appendChild($thumbnail);
$xmldoc->save('sample.xml');
```

Comment: Hey! This works almost! The < in title and description turns out as &gt; and the whole element <thumbnail> is outside </thumbnails>, so it is: </thumbnails> ELEMENT IS HERE </mainXML> See http://pastebin.com/XzaRGsX4

Comment: Thank you.. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666473/prepending-data-to-xml-file

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same as DOM manipulation in JavaScript - it should be something like...

```
$xmlThumbnail = $xmlDoc->createElement('thumbnail');
$xmlTitle = $xmlDoc->createElement('title');
$xmlDescription = $xmlDoc->createElement('discription');

$xmlThumbnail->setAttribute('preview', $sPreview);
$xmlThumbnail->setAttribute('previewurl', $sPreviewURL); //technically in XML attributes must be in lowercase
$xmlThumbnail->setAttribute('thumb', $sThumbnail); //presumably a path?

$xmlThumbnail->appendChild($xmlTitle);
$xmlThumbnail->appendChild($xmlDescription);

$xmlDoc->appendChild($xmlThumbnail);
$xmlDoc->save('/theme1157/sample.xml');
```

Although the `$xmlDoc->appendChild()` will probably need changing if it's a "real" XML document as there should be a container element, so it might be something more like `$xmlDoc->firstChild->appendChild($xmlThumbnail);`

Comment: Not sure that this will work - as XML should only have one root element.

Comment: Yeah - updated it to add in the `$xmlDoc->firstChild->` bit; though I've seen plenty of "not real" XML documents that just spaff out a load of Elements without a container.